# How do I create overlay button in my Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a button which will overlay between 2 layouts.
I am using Linear Layout and added appropriate weight to it.
Have attached a screen shot for reference.

[image]

Here is my XML
tag.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:background="@color/greyColor"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ximgvwCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_big" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/strQ1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your XML code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Try this it will working...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image_top" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bottom"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**View like this**

[image]

Comment: MarginTop does not works for nexus 7, nexus 10 and many tabs. can you please suggest if we can do it without setting margins.

Comment: Hey can you tell me what kind of thing is called when a button is on an imageview where the button is epty inside and has only borders but when cliked it fill colors just like tiktok like button which is transperent from inside and can see the contet throug it but when presed it turns red

Answer (score 0):

You need a relative layout. Set image alignt to right-top and set margin top appropriately.

Comment: setting the margin will not help as I need to support all devices.

Comment: Why not? If you use `dips` to set margin it should adapt to screen density. Anyway, you might align your overflow to the vertical center and parent right so you don't need any margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/firstImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/middleImage" >
    </ImageView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:src="@drawable/share_over" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/YES"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/YES" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/NO"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/NO" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Divide your image TOP-MIDDLE-BOTTOM(layout). Your size looking like above but
you can change width/height size.