# Android: Preventing an ImageButton from covering the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have the following `LinearLayout`, which contains a camera source preview, and an overlay to draw on top of the camera preview. The preview is full screen.

Now, when I attempt to add an `ImageButton` to switch the device camera in use (front/back), I cannot prevent the button from displaying full screen, covering the camera preview completely. I just want this button to be normally sized and sit in the corner, overlaying the camera preview, so the user can press it to change the camera preview being displayed to the front or back camera.

I've tried reading the [Layouts documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), buttons, and several tutorials, but my button appears to not respond to any attributes I change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <foo.bar.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
      android:id="@+id/preview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/switch_camera"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_switch_camera_black_48dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false" />

    <foo.bar.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </foo.bar.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want it to be overlaying, check out [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072946/how-do-i-create-overlay-button-in-my-android-layout which helped me to understand the relationships between the different components in my layout.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have already read this, but Google's Android Developer docs discuss layouts and camera preview: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#preview-layout

"The following layout code provides a very basic view that can be used to display a camera preview. In this example, the FrameLayout element is meant to be the container for the camera preview class. This layout type is used so that additional picture information or controls can be overlayed on the live camera preview images."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_capture"
android:text="Capture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I understand you question correctly, you have another button which is supposed to switch to the camera that is not currently in use i.e. if you are currently taking a picture with the front camera, if you tap the button it should switch to the back camera, and vice versa. Is that correct?

If that's the case, perhaps this is another possibility (just remember to change YOURPACKAGENAME and the activity name in the first LinearLayout below). Both buttons are grouped together in a LinearLayout with the FrameLayout for the camera preview above it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="YOURPACKAGENAME.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:text="Capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switch_camera_front_back"
        android:text="Switch Camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```